# Activity name is not a valid class name

Tags: android-activity, android-studio

Android Studio 1.5 started prompting error while I try to create a new Activity, check attached image:

[image]

Comment: does it always give you this error? I mean even when you try other names?

Comment: Add your package name

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's a bug in Android studio 1.5 ,just add your package name manually and it will get fixed.

Answer (score 27):

its because in Project Pane you haven't selected your java package. Select your java package then try to add new activity or fragment. it worked for me :)

Wrong Selection:

[image]

Right Selection:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

It's because there's no package name selected. You can select the package name using the dropdown:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The warning would appear if "java" folder is selected (in Android Project Explorer)

There is no warning if "app" (top level folder) is selected or any sub folders within "java" folders is selected.

Answer (score 0):

You need click over the app folder.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

make sure the name of the new package is not reserved word,
you can add it to java folder and move it to the desired folder